# Binding Textbox IsEnabled to two different Radiobuttons at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, isenabled

I have three Radiobuttons in my UI (WPF).
By selecting two of them, I want to make a Textbox Enabled. and by selecting the third one the Textbox should be disabled.
shall I use Multibinding? If yes How?

Comment: How about write with Multitriggers.

Comment: Did you *try* with Multibindings, and in that case, did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the `IsEnabled` to the "is not checked"-state of the third RadioButton? Normally a group of radiobuttons is exclusive in that only one can be checked at a time.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <convert:InvertBooleanConverter x:Key="InvertConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radio, Converter={StaticResource InvertConverter}}" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="radio" IsChecked="True"/>
</StackPanel>
```

With a custom converter

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyApplication.Converters {
    public sealed class InvertBooleanConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Picrofo: Just because you like indentation with one space instead of four doesn't mean it's an "improved formatting". And "fixing code" usually means you actually change something in the code, which you didn't do.

Comment: Sorry about that. 'fixed code' for me means that either the code indent or language was changed. In your case, I see that the first code you've posted represents an XML code. So, I've simply changed its language from C# to XML. Please forgive me, I've tried to improve your post. You can always reject my modifications to your post while reviewing my changes. Sorry again. Have a great day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY: I didn't actually see that you added the language tag until now (it didn't show up in the revision history, only in the "suggested" link that I clicked on now). I usually don't add them if they are inferred, which it was in this case. And I didn't accept the change myself, there were apparently three other fellows who did it "for me".

Comment: I've already changed the language of the first code you've posted to XML 22 minutes ago. I'm again sorry for the inconvenience. I did not actually mean to bother you. In anyways, I won't edit your future posts since you do not like my modifications. Have a great day :)

Comment: @PicrofoEGY: Haha, you're not bothering me. Please continue to change posts for the better. And I'll continue to talk back if I don't like them ;)

Comment: And btw, the "xml code" is xaml code. I don't know if google highlights it differently than xml.

Comment: I already understand this. I also understand that every XAML code must be a well-formed XML file and XAML inherits all XML rules & definitions. Also, XAML is based on XML. So, it uses XML for its markup. Have a great day :)

Comment: @Patrick What if In future I want to add more RadioButtons? I want my code to not violate MVVM Rules and design patterns like OCP and so on

Comment: You won't violate the MVVM pattern by binding to another control in the xaml.. Why wouldn't you be able to add more radio buttons in your view? If you want I can add an example of using the MultiBinding, but in the question you specified there's no need for that kind of binding, since your requirement for the IsEnabled property is simple "third radiobutton is not checked".